# alert a message when the time of second input box is less than the first on keyup using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two input boxes of type = "time". I want to alert a message when the time of second input box is less than the first on keyup using jQuery.

Please help....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And your problem/question is...?

Comment: just want to print a message nothing else.

Comment: "I have two input boxes of type = "time". I want to alert a message when the time of second input box is less than the first on keyup using jQuery." This is the question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle empty inputs by yourself

```js
$(".time").keyup(function (e) {

  if($("#time2").val() < $("#time1").val())
  {
    console.log("It's smaller");
  }

});
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for='time1'>time 1</label> <input type='time' class='time' id='time1'></input> <br/>
<label for='time2'>time 2</label> <input type='time' class='time' id='time2'></input>
```